# design issue with the anchor<a> tag

Tags: html, css

I'm new to the html & css design. I have following design of css-

```
span.menu a:link, span.menu a:visited
{
   display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#0000CC;
    background-color:#E8EEFD;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:70px;
    padding:5px;
    border:5px solid gray;
    margin:0px; 
}
```

I want to place three link by using  tag which should be shown in the following manner-

**Calls  Customers  Venders**

and i want to treat them as menu for this they should be placed in horizontal manner. But when i'm running my css design then they placed in the vertical manner like -

calls

customers

vendors

how to do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `display:inline-block` if you want to be able to set the width and have them inline.

This won't work with Internet Explorer 6, an alternative would be using `float:left`. However, this can have complications as the elements will be removed from the normal flow and if there is no other content in the parent element then its height would be reduced to `0`. This could be overcome by adding `overflow:auto` to the parent

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `display: block` use `float: left`.

Answer (score 0):

add the css properties `float:left`